# Will oldList.addAll(newList) inherit the methods from newList also?

Tags: java, list

```
public class CustomVO1 {
   boolean primary;

   public boolean isPrimary() {
      return primary;
   }

   public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
      this.primary = primary;
   }

}


public class CustomVO2 extends CustomVO1{
   boolean primary;

   public boolean getPrimary() {
      return primary;
   }

   public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
      this.primary = primary;
   }

}

public class TestSample {

    List CustomVO1List = new ArrayList();
    List modifiedList = new ArrayList();

    CustomVO1List.clear();
    CustomVO1List.addAll(CustomVO1List);
}
```

Comment: What happened when you ran your code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried to achieve with that code. You added an empty list to an empty list?

Comment: OldList all the values populated from newList .. But I need the getters method from newList in separate jsp ..

Comment: Your lists are instances of ``ArrayList``, they are not at all related to the classes you posted. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: What do you mean by inherit when you are making a method call. Please read OOP concepts first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `addAll()` will not inherit any methods. It will simply append list items from one list to another.

Read the [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) for `List#addAll()`:

> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator (optional operation). The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (Note that this will occur if the specified collection is this list, and it's nonempty.)

Answer (score 0):

The List itself will not inherit anything if that is what you meant. If you were talking about the items in the List, they will still have all their methods no matter what type of List you use:

```
public class Animal {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("<Animal sound>");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("woof");
    }
}
```

If you now add dogs to a list of animals, they will still bark:

```
List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
doglist.add(new Dog());
animalList.addAll(dogList);
animalList.get(0).speak(); //woof
```

(I have not tested this code, sorry for any typos.)